# MS MVC - Can I somehow globally fill in strongly typed ViewData/Model for all my Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewdata

I'd like to supply instance of logged User (or null if nobody logged yet) for all views in my MVC application. I've already succesfully implemented my own ControllerActionInvoker class which overrides InvokeAction and supplies logged user instance in ViewData (controllerContext.Controller.ViewData["LoggedUser"] = xxx). The problem is that I'd like to use the strongly typed Model for passing the logged user instance in whole application. I was thinking about having ApplicationViewDataBase class which could be base class for all my strongly typed ViewData classes and which would provide logged user instance also. I could than easily access logged user instance in all my Views.

Is it possible to fill in the strongly typed globally like I achieved in ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction override? Or is it better to somehow supply my User instance in Page.User? I'd find probably more slick to use Page.User, but also didn't find any solution how to inject my User instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe better way to put User into the HttpContext? In global.asax

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question so just for the benefit of future visitors, this can be done by creating a basecontroller inherited from Controller and handling OnActionExecuted() to add your custom user instances to the view between the controller action and the view.  There's a comprehensive implementation of that here: http://blog.bitdiff.com/2012/05/sharing-common-view-model-data-in.html

If you want that data to be available to your action method things get a bit more complicated as the view won't exist yet.

For POST methods "baseView = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as BaseView" will get you access to the view but you'll need a custom modelbinder to set ViewData.Model (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25250058/2381157).  Unfortunately this isn't a global solution as the modelbinder isn't invoked unless there's something to bind.

One approach that might suit is an ActionFilter or AttributeFilter that injects a value to RouteData or ActionParameters but your action would have to transfer this value to the view.

I couldn't find a clean, simple way to inject this data to the view as it was created and fell back to implementing a thread-safe cache of user instances so that I could retrieve the user instance whenever it was needed without the database query overhead.  That wasn't easy but had other advantages for keeping cross-request user state (which is generally why you'd want to have custom user data available to the controller logic).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add this; it's already available in ASP.NET MVC. Look at ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  It's common for applications to have a custom user class that stores application-specific details for the logged-in user.  The problem isn't finding out who's logged in, it's loading that user object from the database early enough in the response handling for all relevant code to have access to it.