# Asp.net mvc - Accessing view Model from a custom Action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-action-filter

I am trying to access the Model data passed to the view in the action filter OnActionExecuted. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    //get model data
    //...

    sitemap.SetCurrentNode(model.Name);
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The model is at:

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model
```

Comment: @Korayem -  depends on how early you try and access it. If you get it after the controller action has executed it should be an instance of the viewmodel.

Comment: It's null for me in all method (OnActionExecuting, OnActionExecuted, OnResultExecuting, OnResultExecuted)

Comment: please see the [pipeline schematics](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/detailed-aspnet-mvc-pipeline), to understand when the model is set on the viewdata.

Comment: `ViewData.Model` is not available in `OnActionExecution` method of ActionFilter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61694278/understanding-asp-net-mvc-lifecycle-why-is-model-not-available-in-actionfilter/61724680#61724680) if you want to get the model in `OnActionExecution`

Answer (score 20):

I don't know why but `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` is always null even when the model bind is executed before `OnActionExecuted`. I found a solution using the `OnModelUpdated` event to set that property before.

I have the model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = bindingContext.Model;
        base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

After that you need to set the default binder to your new model binder in `Application_Start()` section in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```

Finally you can access your `Model` in an `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class TraceLog : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model now isn't null
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Making the `base.OnActionExecuted()` call the last line of the method solved the 'Model being null' problem for me.

(This is a comment to @Steven Lyons 's answer, but I'm posting as an answer because I can't comment.)

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Core you have an ActionArguments IDictionary on the context, with all the parameters from your method

So if you have the following controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]BaseRequest request)
    {
    }
```

You can access the field like so

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
      var request = context.ActionArguments["request"] as BaseRequest;`
      //do whatever, 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting null - as alternative to @Gustavo Clemente's answer you can try overriding `OnActionExecuted` and passing your viewModel into view in following way:

**Action:**

```
[Breadcrumb("Index")]
public ActionResult UnitIndex()
{
    View(new Answers());
}
```

**Attribute:**

```
public class BreadcrumbAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Page { get; set; }

    public BreadcrumbAttribute(string page)
    {
        Page = page;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = (IBreadcrumbs)filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
        model.Breadcrumbs = BreadcrumbHelper.GetBreadCrumbs(string.Format("{0}", filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]), Page);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is this code from? Strangely I was looking for an answer to this question specifically in the context of wiring up a breadcrumbs solution in a recent project!