# How to get current model in action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a generic action filter, and i want to get current model in the `OnActionExecuting` method. My current implementation is like below:

```
public class CommandFilter<T> : IActionFilter where T : class, new()
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        var model= (T)actionContext.ActionArguments["model"];
    }
}
```

It works well if my all model names are same. But i want to use differnet model names.

How to solve this problem?

**Edit**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(CommandActionFilter<CreateInput>))]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]CreateInput model)
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872796/asp-net-mvc-accessing-view-model-from-a-custom-action-filter

Comment: @user2184057 this is for view model, not request model

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments is just a dictionary,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the arguments to pass when invoking the action. Keys are parameter names.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IDictionary<string, object> ActionArguments { get; }
```

And you need to loop through it if you need to avoid hardcoded parameter name ("model"). From [the same SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351714/2833802) for asp.net:

> When we create a generic action filter that needs to work on a class of similar objects for some specific requirements, we could have our models implement an interface => know which argument is the model we need to work on and we can call the methods though the interface.

In your case you may write something like this:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
{
    foreach(var argument in actionContext.ActionArguments.Values.Where(v => v is T))
    {
         T model = argument as T;
         // your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: "is T" then "as T" some way to improve that code ? you are casting twice from my point of view ....

Comment: I used `context.ActionArguments.Values.OfType<MyType>().Single()` as I knew the specific type I wanted

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ActionExecutingContext.Controller` property

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the controller instance containing the action.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual object Controller { get; }
```

and converting result to [base MVC Controller](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs) get access to model:

```
((Controller)actionExecutingContext.Controller).ViewData.Model
```

Comment: it throws a cast exception : Unable to cast object of type 'MyNamespace.HomeController' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller'.

Comment: oo sorry, i have forgotten `Controller` base definition. I edited code  but now model is null(maybe i miss anything). see my update.

Comment: now I see - you want to get request model, not view model. I have posted another answer

Answer (score 2):

In case your controller action has multiple arguments and in your filter you want to select the one that is bound via `[FromBody]`, then you can use reflection to do the following:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    foreach (ControllerParameterDescriptor param in context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters) {
        if (param.ParameterInfo.CustomAttributes.Any(
            attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof(FromBodyAttribute))
        ) {             
            var entity = context.ActionArguments[param.Name];

            // do something with your entity...
```

Comment: Will I get `given key 'model' was not found in dictionary` if my model was not deserialized correctly?

Comment: I am lacking the  CustomAttributes method in ParameterInfo. Is there any other way to access the custom attributes?