# Remove errors of type Required from ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I want to ignore the errors of type `Required` from the model state, in case of PATCH http request, wherein I am allowing partial updates:

```
public class ValidateModelFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid && context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "PATCH")
        {

            // can't figure out this part
            var modelStateErrors = context.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => context.ModelState[key].Errors);
            // get errors of type required from the modelstate
            // context.ModelState.Remove("attribute_which_failed_due_to_required");


        }
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var modelErrors = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            modelErrors["message"] = "The request has validation errors.";
            modelErrors["errors"] = new SerializableError(context.ModelState);
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(modelErrors);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[ValidateModelFilter]
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] TEntity updatedEntity)
{
    TEntity entity = repository.GetById<TEntity>(id);
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return NotFound(new { message = $"{EntityName} does not exist!" });
    }
    repository.Update(entity, updatedEntity);
    await repository.SaveAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

So, how can I filter out "required" type errors and remove them from the model state.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no better option than doing some reflection. I managed to find required fields using following piece of code.

```
foreach (string parameter in context.ModelState.Keys)
{
    string[] parameterParts = parameter.Split('.');
    string argumentName = parameterParts[0];
    string propertyName = parameterParts[1];
    var argument = context.ActionArguments[argumentName];
    var property = argument.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (property.IsDefined(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true))
    {
        // Your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: your code crashes parameterParts does not contain a dot

Comment: Alright, please add your controller method to your question. Also add ModelState.Keys to clarify things.

Comment: @IzzetYildrim ModelState.Keys simply returns key names as id, name, color etc. It even contains wrong key names if wrong key names are posted in the body

Comment: Strange, it gives me the model parameter and its property in the key. Please add your controller method to your question.

Comment: @IzzetYildirim Your solution only identifies properties that have the required attribute set, it does not say anything about whether this required attribute has resulted in an error, so for me this is not a solution to the OP. Apart from this, parsing the keys for dots looks a bit brittle to me, you could simply use reflection to identify the relevant argument related to [FromBody] and then iterate over the properties (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341478/2477619)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid && context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "PATCH")
        {
            var modelStateErrors = context.ModelState.Where(model =>
            {
                // ignore only if required error is present
                if (model.Value.Errors.Count == 1)
                {
                    // assuming required validation error message contains word "required"
                    return model.Value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage.Contains("required");
                }
                return false;
            });
            foreach (var errorModel in modelStateErrors)
            {
                context.ModelState.Remove(errorModel.Key.ToString());
            }

        }
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var modelErrors = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            modelErrors["message"] = "The request has validation errors.";
            modelErrors["errors"] = new SerializableError(context.ModelState);
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(modelErrors);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not really a solid solution. Relying on an error message is not a good practice at all. Also, you are checking only the first error message in your LINQ, so if there is an error message contains "required" word it will make all your model state invalid. Please consider checking out my solution.

Comment: I agree with @IzzetYildirim that it is highly questionable to depend on the error message to identify whether the required attribute has caused the error, nevertheless, I would not say the answer above is a bad, it's a good proof of concept. The only question left is, how to replace that `ErrorMessage.Contains("required")` part with a solid check. When working with the standard `RequiredAttribute`, the modelState doesn't give you any hints other then the error message and I guess that was the OP's reason to resort to parsing the error message.