# Understanding ASP.NET MVC Lifecycle: Why is Model not available in ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, action-filter

I have created the following Custom ActionFilter, when I try to access the `Model` in the following code, it is null:

```
public class CustomPermissionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        OrganisationBaseController orgBaseController = context.Controller as Controller;
        var vm = ((Controller)context.Controller).ViewData.Model as MyViewModel; // null

        // check if current user has permission to vm.OrganisationId

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand why the `Model` is null? According to [ASP.NET MVC Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application), ActionFilters are executed after Model Binder, so I am not sure why the Model is not available?

[image]

---

This is how I am register the above Action Filter:

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomPermissionCheck]
public ActionResult UpdateBranch(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // so something 
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I have posted the same question on [ASP.NET MVC forum](https://forums.asp.net/p/2166817/6304277.aspx?p=True&t=637247527007872847#_=_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try this to access the request model:

```
MyViewModel vm = context.ActionParameters.Values.OfType<MyViewModel>().SingleOrDefault();
```

[How to get current model in action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895830/how-to-get-current-model-in-action-filter)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked... I am still not sure why the ViewData.Model is not available? Isn't it Model Binder's job to populate ViewData.Model?

Comment: I'm not an expert but ViewData is a dictionary which can contain key-value pairs and is often used to transfers data from the Controller to View (not vice-versa). When compares to Model in model binding, they are just ... two different things...

Comment: I had seen the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895830/how-to-get-current-model-in-action-filter) that you have added to your answer... but that link does not contain the solution that you have included in your answer...